# Angular 8 - Lazy Loading - Weird Child Route Behaviour

Tags: angular, routes

I have an angular 8 application, with feature modules each containing a *-routing.module.ts file containing the routing to it's individual components.

At present, I've got 2 feature modules, one called "Tasks" and one called "Clients".

Both are set up the same way. Here is my **app.routing.ts**:

```
// Task Pages
{ path: 'tasks', loadChildren: './tasks/tasks.module#TasksModule' },

// Client Pages
{ path: 'clients', loadChildren: './clients/clients.module#ClientModule' },
```

Now for some reason, these two modules behave weirdly. Within **clients-routing.module.ts**, I prepend the routes with "clients":

```
  const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'clients', component: ClientListComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'clients/new', component: ClientCreateComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
    { path: 'clients/:id', component: ClientDetailComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
    { path: 'clients/:id/edit', component: ClientEditComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
];
```

And everything works as expected. Navigating to http://baseurl/clients lists all clients, navigating to http://baseurl/clients/1 navigates to the correct client detail and so on.

However, with the **tasks-routing.module.ts**, if I include the tasks prepend like in the clients file, then it doesn't work, none of the routes work as expected, instead, I need to do this:

```
    const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: TaskListComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'new', component: TaskCreateComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: ':id', component: TaskDetailComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
];
```

At which point, the expected routes work, such as http://baseurl/tasks listing all tasks, http://baseurl/tasks/23 show task 23 detail and so on.

Why are they different? I can't seem to see any reason why the two module's routing would differ.

Comment: According to the given **clients-routing.module.ts** file you should have navigated to http://baseurl/clients/clients to list all clients, the **tasks-routing.module.ts** implementation looks correct, since the `tasks` url segment is consumed by the routes listed in **app.routing.ts** and the rest is consumed by the routes listed in **tasks-routing.module.ts**

Comment: @TalOhana, this is exactly what I would expect too, but it's not the case!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like the difference between using `RouterModule.forRoot()` and `RouterModule.forChild()` when registering the route.

I suspect your client route is using the `forRoot` method and the tasks is using the `forChild` method hence the difference.

Angular style guide recommends:

> Only call RouterModule.forRoot() in the root AppRoutingModule (or the AppModule if that's where you register top level application routes). In any other module, you must call the RouterModule.forChild method to register additional routes.

https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: That isn't the case here. I'm only using RouterModule.forRoot() in the app.routing.ts file, everywhere else is using RouterModule.forChild().

Comment: Could you recreate on stackblitz